# SSRS Visual Studio1

Tags: ssrs-2012

In **SSRS Report visual studio**, I have two parameters called Unit and type in this type has two values called with and without ,If I select with value the unit parameter have to hide if I select without The unit parameter have to visible how can I achieve it ??

In SSRS Report visual studio, I have two parameters called Unit and type in this type has two values called with and without ,If I select with value the unit parameter have to hide if I select without The unit parameter have to visible how can I achieve it ??

Comment: You cannot hide parameters based on the value of other parameters. The best you can do is to limit the parameter values based on your main parameters.